# What good Social Networking Site solutions there are?

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, social-networking

What good and **free** Social Networking Site solutions there are?

I tried many options but most of them are either too complicated, too simple, or just do not work...

I tried: Dolphin, DZOIC-Handshakes, elgg, Oxwall, SocialEngine, and some plugins for wp and other CMS.

I don't need much, just: groups, chats, forums, profiles, PM, photos, pages, comments, search, statistics.

Most of which included in pretty much every CMS out there, but not all..

So, what good solutions there are? Also I don't mind paying some money *(I guess no more then $200)*, but I'd prefer if it was a free open source engine.

Of course it should be PHP+MySQL based.

Comment: You should be more clear about the requirements and what where the problems with what you tried. Why where the listed solutions _bad_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From personal POV:

- Drupal-based [Commons](http://commons.acquia.com/)
- [Elgg](http://elgg.org/) ("good" applied here more or less)

Comment: Commons seems like a good option. Thank you, I will try it.